# Need multiple styles dependent on Listboxitem

Tags: wpf, listbox, styles

i have a Listbox, which stores two different object types, based on the same baseclass. (e.g. BaseObject = baseclass and the children of it: CustomPath and CustomImage)

The Datasource:

```
ObservableCollection<BattlegroundBaseObject> _baseObjectCollection;
public ObservableCollection<BattlegroundBaseObject> BaseObjectCollection
{
    get { return _baseObjectCollection?? (_baseObjectCollection= new ObservableCollection<BaseObject>()); }
}
```

The Listbox databinding: `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding BaseObjectCollection}"`

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Name="ListBoxPathLineStyle">
        <Setter Property="Template">

            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Name="BattlegroundObjectControlTemplate">

                    <Path Stroke="{Binding ObjectColor}" StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThickness}" Data="{Binding PathGeometryData}" x:Name="PathLine" Opacity="{Binding Opacity}">
                    </Path>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Effect" TargetName="PathLine">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DropShadowEffect Color="CornflowerBlue" ShadowDepth="3" BlurRadius="10" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

I want to add to the ControlTemplate where the Path is, also a Image and to differ it by  type or a property. doesnt matter.

anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add to `ListBox` resources `DataTemplate` for each type.

In my example classes `Car` and `Motorbike` derived from `Vehicle` class.

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Car}">
            <StackPanel Background="Red">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Motorbike}">
            <StackPanel Background="Orange">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

**EDIT:**

You can add style for `ListBoxItem` to resources:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Effect">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DropShadowEffect Color="CornflowerBlue" ShadowDepth="3" BlurRadius="10" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Car}">
            <StackPanel Background="Red">                       
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />                        
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Motorbike}">
            <StackPanel Background="Orange">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: thx that works, but how do i set the trigger for isSelected in the Styles now? the targetname cant find it anymore sry.. very new on wpf :).. and xaml is really different from the things before.

Comment: @user3012180 check my answer again :)

Comment: oh ok :).. but i still got one problem now. when i paint a new line, or move one of the objects, a gray rectangle is shown, while drawing, until i finished it. also when i select and move the object. any ideas how to fix this last thing? then it would be perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

You could define some DataTemplates for your different classes. They determine how the classes are displayed. I've been using them to display derived classes differently when working with a collection of the base class.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type CustomPath}">
    <TextBlock Text="This is a CustomPath"/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type CustomImage}">
    <TextBlock Text="This is a CustomImage"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are changing the style of the controls that WPF is using to render your bound data. A better way to do this is to provide WPF with a way of generating the correct controls. Ignore the `ListBoxItem` and use `DataTemplate`s for your actual objects.

First you need to tell the Window or control how to find your types.

```
<Window or UserControl
...
    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:yourNamespace"
>
```

Then you can provide WPF with a way to show your objects e.g.

```
<DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type model:CustomPath}">
  <Path Stroke="{Binding ObjectColor}" StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThickness}" 
    Data="{Binding PathGeometryData}" x:Name="PathLine" Opacity="{Binding Opacity}"/>
  <!-- maybe use a binding from the Path.Effect back to the IsSelected and ValueConverters 
    to re-apply the selection effect-->
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type model:CustomImage}">
  <Image Src="{Binding SomeProperty}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Now all you need to do is to make these available to the ListBox in some way. Almost every element in WPF can have `.Resources` added to it, so you could choose to do these across the entire window

```
<Window ...>
  <Window.Resources>
     <DataTemplate .../>
     <DataTemplate .../>
  </Window.Resources>
  ...
  <ListBox .../>
</Window>
```

or you can apply it more locally

```
<Window ...>
  ...
  <ListBox>
    <ListBox.Resources>
       <DataTemplate .../>
       <DataTemplate .../>
    </ListBox.Resources>
  </ListBox>
</Window>
```

And this way your listbox definition can become much neater too, e.g. if you are using `Window.Resources`

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding BaseObjectCollection}"/>
```