# Display Error using Datatemplate

Tags: wpf, path, listbox, drawing

today you helped me with [Need multiple styles dependent on Listboxitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20090798/need-multiple-styles-dependent-on-listboxitem)

But now i get a gray rectangle while drawing or moving the objects.

Picture with how it should look like, and how it looks like when iam drawing a line:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_F04v1afwM5c0kteExsamlMcHM/edit?usp=sharing

here is the code i used:

```
                     <ListBox.Resources>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:PathLine}">
                           <Path  Stroke="{Binding ObjectColor}" StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThickness}" Data="{Binding PathGeometryData}" x:Name="PathLine" Opacity="{Binding Opacity}" >
                            </Path>
                        </DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:ImageObject}">
                            <Image Source="H:\Dropbox\WPF Projekte\Arena WPF\ArenaProgram\ArenaProgram\Pictures\tree1.png" Name="imgPic1" Width="100" Height="75" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Effect">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <DropShadowEffect Color="Crimson" ShadowDepth="3" BlurRadius="10" />
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.Resources>
```

hope someone can help me :)

Comment: Your link doesn't show anything.

Comment: ups.. thx now it should work :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not seeing any grey rectangles in your image.

Comment: iam drawing the line there, and the background should be the hexagon you can see at the bottom and right end of the picture. Or some other lines i made before. but instead, i get the line in a gray rectangle, and i dont know what to do.. sry dont know what it is, thats why its so hard for me to explain.. _:)

Comment: Can you show us a screen shot of this grey rectangle?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_F04v1afwM5c0kteExsamlMcHM/edit?usp=sharing   how it should look, and how it looks (with the rectangle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! Finally, I know what you're talking about. :)

It seems to me that that (in my opinion, white) rectangle with a light crimson border is the `ListBoxItem` object. You added a `Style` that tells the `ListBoxItem` to display a crimson glow around its edge when it is selected, so *that* is what you are seeing. Try adding a `Setter` which sets the `Background` property to `Transparent`:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Effect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DropShadowEffect Color="Crimson" ShadowDepth="3" BlurRadius="10"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

If that doesn't work, you might think about removing the `Trigger` altogether.

Comment: hmm doesnt work :/ still the same problem.. can you tell me why the path is in a rectangle when iam drawing/selectiong it? when i had the path in the ListBox.ItemContainerStyle it worked perfectly.. but then i had the problems i posted before :)   If i remove the style with the crimson border, the rectangle is still there..

Comment: How very strange. I'm running out of ideas... is there any reason why you're doing that in a `ListBox` anyway?

Comment: no not really. like i said iam new at wpf and found it in a tutorial.. one last question.. is there any chance to differ the style in the ListBox.ItemContainerStyle based on the childrentype which are stored here? '<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding BattlegroundObjects}" '    Is it possible that the rectangle box i see all the time.. is the itemcontainer in which i definded the datatemplate?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it is... I was just coming back to ask if you had defined something for the `ItemContainerStyle`. This `Style` defines what the `ListBoxItem` looks like, so if you have set some `Background` in there, either remove it or set it to `Transparent`.

Comment: hmm its still not working :/.. i really dont know why the ItemContainerStyle doesnt fit itself on a given shape :/.. pls have a look at this, do you think this might work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099688/using-different-itemcontainerstyles-based-on-objecttype

Comment: Dude, if I were you, I'd get out of the `ListBox` altogether... as far as I can tell, you don't need any aspect of it and all these things are just making your job far more complicated than they need to be... oh and that last link is *not* the answer... that would just make things worse for you.

Comment: hmm ok thank you. so what should i use instead of a listbox then? any suggestions?

Comment: A [`Canvas` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas(v=vs.110).aspx) is the usual control to use for drawing on.