# using different itemcontainerstyles based on objecttype

Tags: wpf, styles, listboxitem

I have a Listbox with an collection

```
ObservableCollection<BaseObject> _baseObjects;
public ObservableCollection<BattlegroundBaseObject> BaseObject
{
    get { return _baseObjects?? (_baseObjects= new ObservableCollection<BaseObject>()); }
}
```

the collection has two different children from BaseObject. one is a path the other an image.. more are coming

i need now two different ItemContainerStyles based on the childrens

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

     <Style BasedOn="ListBoxItem" TargetType="ListBoxItem"  x:Name="ListBoxPathLineStyle">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                     <Path Stroke="{Binding ObjectColor}" Data="{Binding PathGeometryData}" />                        
               </ControlTemplate>
             </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>

       <!-- Alternative Template for other type -->
      <Setter Property="Template">
           <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                   <Image Source="howTheHellCares.png"/>                                           
               </ControlTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>               
   </Style> 
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

at the moment the lower setter is always taken, but i need to differ it.. sb knows how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that you have the wrong idea about the `ItemContainerStyle`... the clue is in the name... it is the `Style` for *the container*, not for the *content*. By that I mean that it `Style`s the `ListBoxItem` and not the data contained within the item... literally, the container of the item.

What (it seems) you are really looking for is the `DataTemplate` that you can specify for the `ItemTemplate` property. The `DataTemplate` has a `DataType` property specifically so that you can take advantage of the properties of the relevant class. You *could* use a [`DataTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to switch between `DataTemplate`s on a per item basis, but there is another way.

What you can do is to specify a `DataTemplate` for each data type you have, but *don't give them an `x:Key` value*. This way, WPF will automatically apply them to any relevant data type object that it finds that doesn't have one explicitly set.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourXmlNamespacePrefix:SomeDataType}">
    ...
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourXmlNamespacePrefix:SomeOtherDataType}">
    ...
</DataTemplate>
```

You can either leave the `ItemContainerStyle` empty, or define what the container will look like for every item, regardless of the type.

Comment: Big plus this is part of a resource dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

     <Style BasedOn="ListBoxItem" TargetType="ListBoxItem"  x:Name="ListBoxPathLineStyle">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                     <Path Stroke="{Binding ObjectColor}" Data="{Binding PathGeometryData}" />                        
               </ControlTemplate>
             </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>

      <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding={Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource MyTypeToTemplaceConverter}} Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>                                                                
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Image Source="howTheHellCares.png"/>                                           
                        </ControlTemplate>                        
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>  
           </DataTTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>   
    </Style> 
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: hey thanks for the quick answer, but can you explain me this line? i dont get it :/   <DataTrigger Binding={Binding , Converter={StaticResource MyTypeToTemplaceConverter}} Value="True">

Comment: That line won't actually compile. Normally, you can specify that a `Binding` should use the whole data source value rather than a property of that data source... you can do that like this: `Text="{Binding}"`. However, if you have other properties of the `Binding` in the statement, then you must use the `.` character to specify the same. Therefore that line should be like this: `Binding="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource MyTypeToTemplaceConverter}}"`. It could also be written as: `Binding="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource MyTypeToTemplaceConverter}}"`.

Comment: @eranotzap, it seems to me that you are doing everything you can at the moment to get more reputation. By that I mean answering all the questions. However, your answers to the last two questions that I looked at contain errors, or just don't work/compile at all. Maybe you should slow down a bit and concentrate on checking your answers before posting them? Just a suggestion.

Comment: @Sheridan that's not my what i'm doing at all , some of my answers are psedu code which i write here not in vs , they provide the way , if some don't conpile becuase a comma is missing the reader should relaize it and make the fix on his own.

Comment: sry iam still dont getting it, whats the mytypetotemplaceconverter should exactly do..  :/ sry.. :)

Comment: @Sheridan FYI {Binding} for me works just like {Binding Path=.} 
 in vs 2012. , when writing binding in code you need to add the dot explictly

Comment: @eranotzap, `{Binding}` works just like `{Binding Path=.}` in VS 2010 too, but that wasn't my point. My point was that you can't use `Binding` without the `'.'` *if you are setting any other `Binding` properties* as you were. If you set any other properties of the `Binding` such as `Converter`, then you *have to* use the `'.'`... if you don't, Visual Studio (even 2012 and 2013) will *raise a compilation error*. To be clear, I'm talking about the inline `Binding` syntax that you used and not the verbose XML declaration syntax.

Comment: @eranotzap, regarding my earlier comment, I was trying to be helpful to you. You're much more likely to get votes by either checking that your answer code actually works, or at least mention that it is just pseudo code and that you can't test it at the moment.

Comment: @Sheridan ok thanks , and you where helpfull i didn't relaize i had to use the dot , 10x.

Comment: `Path=.` is only required when using a two-way binding, converters and other properties of a `{Binding}` can be set without a `Path` value, as long as a two-way binding is not being used.